# Problem opening up text file of the downloadPath with gedit

Tags: python, nexus

After downloading the dependencies from nexus, I have a download path for the data to be in, but I wasn't able to open the textile its not responding, why is this so?

```
  for item in data["items"]:
     for asset in item["assets"]:
             fileurl = asset["downloadUrl"]
             print(fileurl)
             downloadPath = '/home/centos/'
             filename = downloadPath + fileurl.split('/')[-1]# '\' for Windows
             outfile = open(filename, "w")
             outfile.write(str(urllib.request.urlopen(fileurl).read()))
             outfile.close()
             if data["continuationToken"] is None:
                sys.exit()
             else:
             #construct pagination url and loop
                url = baseurl + 'components?continuationToken=' + data["continuationToken"] + '&repository=' + downloadRepository
             return
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: I tried opening the text file in the files, but It wasn't responding at all. There's no error message, I couldn't get it to open, the file size is 7.0MB

Comment: Do you mean, that your code works but when you try to open the downloaded file with an editor (Gedit) it just hangs.?

Comment: exactly. upon waiting for a while longer, it started downloading inside the text file.

Comment: I'm still do not understand what are you trying and what's the problem.
Please try to elaborate more you question.